# Is it possible to store reusable VBA code in a library and call from Outlook?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have code written in Outlook 2010 VBA that I want to share with co-workers (an Outlook rule runs that calls the code, which saves the current e-mail to a network folder as a text file).  What I would like to do is save the VBA code in a library somewhere on the network, and have Outlook call it there.  This way, others can call the same code and there is one set of code that all instances of Outlook can point to.  If you can point me to info on setting this up I would appreciate it!

I do a similar thing in VBscript programs, using executeglobal to basically run a file containing the functions (acts like an include file) and am looking for how to do it in VBA.

Comment: You could save your VBA project as OTM file. Your colleagues could than use your OTM file via VBA - Tools - References. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460036/vbaproject-otm-deployment and http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=28

Comment: I use an add-in in Excel VBA as a code library [XL Dennis' .Net Co Library](http://xldennis.wordpress.com/2007/12/03/net-co-library-is-released/). I don't know if it works with Outlook...

Answer (score 2):

Well it seems its not as easy as I was hoping.  After perusing the links supplied by MP24 (Thanks MP24!), I learned the Outlook OTM file is not really intended to be shared.  It errored for a colleague when I saved it to a network drive and she tried to use it via tools/references.  To share code, one can export it as a .bas file, and another user can import it.  This will add it to their own code if some exists already.  The proper way seems to be to write an add-in, but that is beyond the scope of what I need for what I am doing.  So, if a colleague wants to use my code I'll export and they can import it.  The trouble is if I change something they will have to delete it and re-import.  Oh well.