# How to call the quit/close event in outlook 2007 VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

The question is simple, yet hard to achieve for me for some reason. How can I get to fire the quit/close event when outlook 2007 is being closed?

I want do display a Yes/No msgbox in VBA which executes code depending on the option chosen when outlook is being closed.

I thought I had the solution using:

```
Dim WithEvents myOlApp As Outlook.Application

Sub Initialize_handler()
    Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
End Sub

Private Sub myOlApp_Quit()
    MsgBox "TEST"
End Sub
```

First I tried to insert it into my Module but this gave me the `Only valid in object modules` error. So then I created a new class module and pasted the code in here (which gave no errors) but still the event wont fire. What is going wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Not sure if its the same in 2007 as 2010. But there is an Microsoft outlook object on the project for mine and then there is a `private sub Application_Quit` even in it. So you can call a function from that

Comment: Tried to insert the sub in both the class module as the regular module but sadly didn't fired.

Comment: @Sam: Just saw your comment. I have deleted my answer. That works for me too. That is a valid answer provided 2007 behave the same way as 2010  which I believe it will (unless I am wrong) You may want to put that an answer?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Your answer did the trick, Thanks! One question though, the modules is saved in the VBAProject.OTM file. This file is located in a shared folder so that everyone that uses their outlook get the updates / code. When using the `ThisOutlookSession` does that mean I have to paste my `Private Sub Application_Quit()` at each outlook user that uses the code in their respective 'own sessions' ? I assume that only this one user now gets the msgbox (the user of which ThisSession) belongs to.

Comment: Is [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460036/vbaproject-otm-deployment) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")

There is no need to create a new Outlook instance. You should use the Application property availble in Outlook VBA.

```
Private Sub Application_Quit() 
  MsgBox "Goodbye, " & Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").CurrentUser  
End Sub
```

Take a look at the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article in MSDN.

Comment: Have you seen the comments below the question? :)

Comment: Did anybody say about `CreateObject("Outlook.application")`?

Comment: After Sam's comment, that line becomes redundant ;)

Comment: I think I am being polite. Please do not take advantage of that :)

Comment: For anyone else stumbling along this, I found that this code must be within `ThisOutlookSession`; it would not run for me as-is from within another module