# Public storage of outlook macros

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a macro that select selected emails, analyses them and write to excel, marking the email as read and moving it out of the way. 
The problem is the mailbox will be accessed by other users on different computers who will wish to use the macro.

So where can I store the macro so all can see and access it?

Answer (score 1):

VBA scripts are not designed to be shared,  you really need to create a COM addin.

That being said, see http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=28 - you will need to copy the VbaProject.otm etc. files.

Answer (score 1):

There is a command line switch that points to a centrally saved .otm file. When used the user will not have access to their own VBA code, if any.

/altvba otmfilename - Opens the VBA program specified in otmfilename, instead of %appdata%\microsoft\outlook\vbaproject.otm.

**Outlook 2016 and 2013** - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Command-line-switches-for-Outlook-for-Windows-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6

**Outlook 2013** - http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/2013/command-lines-for-outlook-2013/

Opens the VBA files specified in otmfilename, rather than %appdata%\Microsoft\Outlook\VbaProject.OTM Use this switch when you need to run macros not in your default VBAProject file.

This switch is not supported in Outlook 2013 by default; you need to create a registry value to enable it.

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Security

DWORD: EnableAltVba

Data Value of 1 to enable the switch.

**Outlook 2010** - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Command-line-switches-for-Outlook-2010-ce2b9143-ceca-48ac-bffc-c3059a4c5919

/altvba otmfilename - Opens the VBA program specified in otmfilename, instead of %appdata%\microsoft\outlook\vbaproject.otm.

Note: This command line switch is only available if the following Windows registry DWORD value is set to 1. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Security\EnableAltVba

stackoverflow question: [VbaProject.OTM deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460036/vbaproject-otm-deployment)

"This allows me to update only one file to get all computers updated. Obviously, if the file is big and the server's ping is on the high side, it may delay the launch of Outlook. The other problem with this method is that everybody will have to shut down Office if you want to update the OTM file on the server ..." Possible solutions in that answer.

Comment: Is there any reason I should not copy and paste the code into an email, save it as a draft in the email account, and anyone needing it could copy it via Alt-F11 to there own .otm ?

Comment: Essentially what I do except I mail the code, go to their desks copy it and create the button to run it. (This advice got me a downvote.)